# Screenshot with rightclick

Tags: screenshot

This seems to be system wide and only with "elementary right click" windows. So for example, in chromium if you right click, you can still take screenshots.

To reproduce:
1. Open any elementary application (I think only GTK+ Applications have this problem, Need to look into this further)
2. Right click so you get the right click options menu
3. Take a sceenshot with prt sc
4. No screenshot will be taken

Comment: I have the same problem.Very annoying

Comment: I opened a bug report on this issue.
https://answers.launchpad.net/screenshot-tool/+question/290761